# Переименовать Android приложение из кода

Tags: android

Собственно, возник вопрос, как можно переименовать android приложение, когда оно уже запущено у пользователя на устройстве, т.е. дать возможность пользователь задать произвольное имя приложению?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы говорите о том, что задается в манифесте с помощью `android:label="@string/app_name"`, то ответ - никак. Оно доступно только по чтению.

Но может просто хотите поменять название в заголовке активити? тогда это просто делается с помощью метода `setTitle()`.

Comment: да именно о том, что задается в манифесте. Т.е. в ресурсных файлах никак ничего нельзя изменить из кода?

Comment: никак - они доступны только по чтению.

Comment: Подождите, а как же реализовали это разработчики Avast? Кто устанавливал их "анти-вор", тот знает, что во время установки можно было указать собственное название этому приложению.

Comment: не знаю, как там "авастовский антивор" живет (хотя таким программам не место на телефоне), но подозреваю, что он просто скачивает правильный мелкий apk с сайта, который по факту является запускалкой. Либо просто запускает другую программу, которая "патчит" оригинал. Но здесь есть проблема, что нужно будет иметь сертификат, что бы подписать.

Любители писать антивирусы известны тем, что любят плевать на все стандарты и заходить иногда поглубже вирусов.

Answer (score 0):

```
@string/appname=res/values/strings.xml/appname-название
```